# Getting data from an API array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I have a React component that has to retrieve the items of an array containing objects that comes from an API. The array, `favorites`, is structured with items like this:

```
0:Object
  _id:Object
    ObjectId:"5db9cd4a1a088e7756516889"
```

where each of the items hold the id for a specific movie within a collection called `movies`. I have been trying to use `map` to get the data from this array with this piece of code:

```
{favorites.map(favorite =>
                      (<li key={favorite}>
                        <p className="favorites">
                          {JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('movies')).find(movie => movie._id === favorite).title}
```

I have been failing miserably because I looked so much into this code. Could any of you throw some light in it? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
{favorites.map(favorite.ObjectId =>
                      (<li key={favorite.ObjectId}>
                        <p className="favorites">
                          {JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('movies')).find(movie => movie._id === ObjectId).title}
```

If favorites is an array containing objects, then that means favorite is a single object with keys and values. So select the relevant key in your loop. Which seems to be ObjectId

Answer (score 0):

```
{favorites.map(({_id}) =>
                      (<li key={_id.ObjectId}>
                        <p className="favorites">
                          {JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('movies')).find(movie => movie._id === _id.ObjectId).title}</p></li>)
}
```

This should do the job, assuming JSON structure is like `[{_id: {ObjectId: "abc"}}, {}...]`.